# Show all available fields in references

Tags: bibtex

I'm using bibtex and I create my references with `\bibliography{myref}`. My question is what to do so that everything is shown. 
An example:

```
@misc{Clason,
author = {Clason,Christian},
title = {{Numerische Mathematik I}},
howpublished = {Vorlesungsskript},
url= "\url{http://www.uni-graz.at/people/clason/teaching/numa12/NuMaSkript.pdf}",
year={2012},
Institution={{Institut für Mathematik und Wissenschaliches Rechnen
Karl-Franzens-Universität Graz}},
}
```

Do my BibTeX entry and LaTeX not show the Institution and the URL?

Comment: For `bibtex`, the output is is governed by styles. In other words, it's the style you use that will determine which fields will be printed and which ones will be ommited. Another approach is to use the `biblatex/biber` combo instead. `:)` Just a note: if I'm not mistaken `institution` is not available for `misc` entries.

Answer (score 7):

It is the bibliography style file that determines which fields of a given bib entry are shown. Some style files that show most standard fields of an entry of type `@misc` are `plainnat`, `unsrtnat`, and `abbrevnat`.

*Addendum*: As others have already pointed out, `institution` is *not* a standard field for bib entries of type `@misc`. (AFAICT, `institution` is recognized as a standard field only for entries of type `@techreport`.) BibTeX's rule for dealing with unrecognized fields is simple: they are ignored. For the entry at hand, you'll probably need to combine the information of your current `howpublished` and `institution` fields into a single, new `howpublished` field.

Answer (score 5):

In general, not every entry type (here: `misc`) supports every field (here: `institution`); the list of required and optional fields can be found in the [bibtex documentation](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/bibtex/base/btxdoc.pdf). If you need to change this, I would second the recommendation to switch to `biblatex` instead of hacking `bibtex` (although this might not be feasible if a deadline looms).

This does not address the question as posed, but here's a solution for the concrete problem: Since `misc` does not provide the `institution` field, I would just put that information into the `howpublished` field and select the `plainurl` (or `abbrvurl`, `alphaurl`, `unsrturl`) bibliographystyle. You also don't need the `\url` command, as this is automatically added.

```
@misc{Clason,
    author = {Clason, Christian},
    title = {{Numerische Mathematik I}},
    howpublished = {Vorlesungsskript, Institut f\"ur Mathematik und Wissenschaftliches Rechnen, Karl-Franzens-Universit\"at Graz},
    url = {http://www.uni-graz.at/people/clason/teaching/numa12/NuMaSkript.pdf},
    year = {2012}
}
```

The `plainurl` etc. styles also add the `lastchecked` field, which can be used to give the date when you last verified the page was there.

Comment: Finally someone that gives a link to the official bibtex documentation. Thank you!
Edit: I found another more official link for the documentation: https://ctan.org/pkg/bibtex

Answer (score 2):

I was also interested in this very same thing, and in the end came up with a small `pygtk` (Python 2.7/Gtk2) application, called `bibview` (`bibview_pygtk.py`); released here:

- http://sourceforge.net/p/sdaaubckp/code/HEAD/tree/xtra/tex/bibview/

I've written a bit about it in the README, which should be visible at the above link; otherwise, here are some screenshots:

[image: bibview_pygtk_01.png]

[image: bibview_pygtk_03.png]

Answer (score 1):

Which fields of a bibtex entry are shown in the bibliography is governed by the bst file you are using, that is the configuration in `\bibliographystyle{<style>}`. As far as I know, there is no stock bst style which would show all the fields, but you should check yourself in the examples of bibtex styles, e.g., [here](http://www.cs.stir.ac.uk/~kjt/software/latex/showbst.html), or simply google `"bibtex styles examples"`.

If you really want to show all the fields in your document, create a bst file of your liking (for all bibentry types include all fields in some order) and install it. To create a bst file, you do not necessarily have to understand the programming language of bibtex style files, try some bst file generator. E.g., one included with [Bib-it](http://bib-it.sourceforge.net/) seems to [work](http://bib-it.sourceforge.net/help/generateBibstyle.php) and there are other.

To install a bibtex file, put your `bst` file into `$HOME/texmf/bibtex/bst/` and rerun texhash. See also [here](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~hildebr/tex/tips-customstyles.html), or google around.

Comment: I'm very interested in this too, i.e., a standard command for forcing all fields to show.